# Why can't execute 'ifstream' in this state

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    char b;
    ifstream in("a.txt");

    if (!(in >> a))
        in >> b;
    if (!(in >> a))
        in >> b;
    in >> b;
    in >> b;

    cout << a;
    cout << b;
}//source code

5 a b c d e
//a.txt
```

1. If there is a int in the file I want to read it as int and
2. If there is a char in the file I want to read it as char.
3. why can't read 'char b' after try to read b as int?

Answer (score 4):

After the failed read of the `int` the [`failbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) of the stream is set. This causes all subsequent read attempts to fail. It is possible to [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error before attempting a subsequent read.

Note that [`operator>>(int&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) will skip leading white space. If a space is a valid character in your application then the failed `int` read would have an undesired side effect. If the file is line oriented then an alternative would be to use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read into a (which is an int) twice. You should read once in a and then only in b.
However, I'd suggest you to use a more general approach, which reads line by line.